# React onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave bug, not working consistently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mouseevent

I am having issues with React `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`, sometimes the events are not firing when it should

I am using `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` to show/hide a React Portal Modal tooltip panel:

[image]

[image]

the issue:

if the mouse cursor hovers over the images slowly, `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` works as expected, but if the mouse cursor hovers over the image rapidly ( horizontally ), the code breaks, and multiple tooltip panels are shown ( because `onMouseLeave` failed to trigger )

here is the video link showing the issue:
https://www.veed.io/view/7669d6c4-6b18-4251-b3be-a3fde8a53d54?sharingWidget=true

here is the codesandbox link for bug I mentioned:
https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-satoshi-rjk38e

any help is appreciated

Comment: Maybe you should use EventListeners and cleanup function from UseEffect like in this example : [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y4y6vg?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2FTerm.js)

Comment: @MB_ converted it to use `addEventListener()` and `useRef()` does not seems to make any differences, `onMouseLeave` still fails to trigger when mouse cursor hovers over the image rapidly ( horizontally )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause for the "lost events" is not the event listeners not firing. The problem is that you mix React code, which operates on the virtual DOM, with "classical" JS code, which operates on the browser DOM. These two DOMs are out-of-sync most of the time, which causes the hiccups that you see.

Try to remove all code that directly accesses the DOM and operate on React components (i.e. in the virtual DOM) only.

Here is an stripped-down example how to implement your tooltip in React-only style:

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-villani-c0xv24?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing out the cause, but without using javascript `.querySelector()` how should I write the logic for hiding/showing the `tooltip panel` when: 
`onmouseout` => if cursor leaves `justified box` and enters `tooltip panel` [ show/keep the tooltip panel on ] else hide if it ( not in `tooltip panel` )?

Comment: `onMouseEnter` sets a state variable `showTooltip` to `true`, `onMouseLeave` sets this variable to `false`; The tooltip panel is only rendered if `showTooltip==true`. Both event listeners are attached to different elements, so that the 'mouseEnter' event is handled when the mouse enters an invisible div hovering over the center of the `JustifiedBox`, while the `mouseLeave` event is handled by a div that contains both the `JustifiedBox` and the `AlbumDetailsPanel`. Does the mini-app in my codesandbox show the desired behaviour? If so, you may not need query selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Great question I had a similar problem with one of my components and global state management.
After looking at your code it looks you should add the `onFocus` and `onBlur` events.

Example

```js
<div
  onMouseOver={() => handleEnter()}
  onMouseOut={() => handleExit()}
>
```

Becomes

```js
<div
  onMouseOver={() => handleEnter()}
  onFocus={() => handleEnter()}
  onMouseOut={() => handleExit()}
  onBlur={() => handleExit()}
>
```

This also solves a problem of mobile not having the same mouse state.

Hope this helps happy coding!

Comment: this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

As Steffen Frank correctly pointed out, using DOM events is often risky...
I used another strategy using the React `onMouseMove` on the `main` container, in index.js

```
const [hoveredClasses, setHoveredClasses] = useState([]);

const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;

  let elementMouseIsOver =
    document.elementFromPoint(x, y)?.closest(".c-justified-box") ||
    document.elementFromPoint(x, y)?.closest(".tooltip");

  let classes = elementMouseIsOver?.classList
    ? Array.from(elementMouseIsOver?.classList)
    : [];
  console.log(
    "[ c-justified-box ] > Mouse Move ----------------------------->",
    x,
    y,
    elementMouseIsOver,
    classes
  );

  // check if we need to cal setState
  if (
    (classes.length === 0 && hoveredClasses.length !== 0) ||
    !classes.every((classItem) => hoveredClasses.includes(classItem))
  ) {
    setHoveredClasses(classes);
  }
};
```

And

```
<main className={styles.main} onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
```

So on mouse move:

- we get the element under the mouse
- we check if that element classes are exactly the same as the classes we previously stored in state.

If no, we set the state with those classes. That triggers a redraw for the whole `main` component, so each of the `JustifiedBox` are also redrawn.

We are passing them the `hoveredClasses` array... so within each of them, a boolean is set to decide to show the modal or not.

```
const showFloatingDetailPanel = props.hoveredClasses.includes(
  props.new_Album.slug
);
```

Has you can see... We use the `props.new_Album.slug` which was already used as a `div` class for `c-justified-box`

```
className={"c-justified-box" + " " + props.new_Album.slug}
```

We just need to also pass it to the `AlbumDetailsPanel` as a props, to do the same with the modal main div.

JustifiedBox.js:

```
<AlbumDetailsPanel
  slug={props.new_Album.slug}
  t_ref={floating}
  //...
```

AlbumDetailPanel.js:

```
<div
  className={"tooltip" + " " + props.slug}
```

So every times the `hoveredClasses` do not match, we setState... And that state will be used by each component to decide to show their associated `AlbumDetailsPanel`. It is now impossible to have more than on shown.

And this simplifies everything in JustifiedBox.js, since we got rid of:

- `handleAlbumMouseEnter`
- `handleAlbumMouseOut`
- `handleTooltipMouseEnter`
- `handleTooltipMouseOut`
- the 3 `useEffect`

The updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mouse-events-for-so-question-72640250-xgrdoi)